# what is regular expression not generated over {a,b}?

Tags: regex, string, regex-negation

I am really stuck with these 2 questions for over 2 days now. I'm trying to figure out what the question means. My tutor is out of town too.

Question 1: Write a regular expression for the only strings that are not generated over {a,b} by the expression: `(a+b)****a(a+b)****`. Explain your reasoning.

And I tried the second question. Do you think is there any better answer than this one?

What is a regular expression of a set of strings that contain an odd number of `a`s or exactly two `b`s `(a((a|b)(a|b))****|bb)` I know to represent any odd length of a's, the RE is `a((a|b)(a|b))****`

Comment: "generated over `{a, b}`" means that `{a, b}` is _the alphabet_. The string `"zzz"` is obviously not generated by the regex, but since `z` is not part of the alphabet, it's out of the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start for the first question. First consider the strings that this regular expression generates:

```
(a+b)*a(a+b)*
```

- It must begin with `a` AND
- Every `b` must have at least one an `a` immediately before it AND
- There must either be an `aab` or else the string must end in `a`.

The inverse of this is:

- It must not begin with `a` OR
- There is at least one `b` not after an `a` OR
- The string consists only of repetitions of `ab`.

For the second question you should check that you have understood the question correctly. Your interpretation seems to be:

> What is the regular expression for the set of strings that contain either (an odd number of a's and any number of b's) or (exactly two b's and **no a's**).

But another interpretation is this:

> What is the regular expression for the set of strings that contain either (an odd number of a's and any number of b's) or (exactly two b's and **any number of a's**).

Comment: oh man....i am looking at what u said...but its so confusing..... i still dont get it.... like it must begin with a? is this a part of the question? does the + sign stand for alteration |?

Comment: @Loop: Is it possible that you have copied the questions incorrectly?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the + means an or operator. Then my answer would be correct again... (already deleted it). Going to undelete it again, just for the case. :)

Comment: @Loop: I think the main problem is that you don't know what is meant by `(a+b)`. Go find your course notes and look up what you were taught, then update your question with that information. I see you are using `|` for alternation another place in your question. It would surprise me if you were taught two different symbols for the same thing, but the question would be a lot easier if `(a+b)` meant alternation.

Answer (score 1):

To match two `a`'s you would use something like `aa` right?
Now we know that the `+` is a quantifier for 1 or more and the `*` is a quantifier for 0 or more. So if we want to repeat that entire pattern, we can put it in a group and repeat the entire pattern like so: `(aa)+`.

That would match:

- `aa`
- `aaaa`

But not:

- `a` (because `aa` requires at least 2 items)`
- `aaa` (because `aa` will match the first two, but you'll have an extra `a`)

And if we want to make that odd an even, we can simply add one extra `a` outside of the group like so: `a(aa)+`. However, since we wanted an odd amount without a specific minimum we shouldn't use `+` since that will require atleast 3 `a`'s.

So the entire answer would be: `(bb|a(aa)*)`

Comment: Correcting a homework problem with zero explanation as to why the initial answer was incorrect seems kind of uncool.

Comment: @Ladenedge: Fair enough, I'll add an explanation :)

Comment: Nothing is said about not allowing b's in the string of "odd number of a's". I would say the expression should be: `(bb|b*a(b*ab*a)*b*)`, so that arbitrarily many b's can appear between the odd number of a's.

Comment: That's very well possible phild, I haven't thought of that. If that is the case than my answer is indeed incorrect.

Comment: Why the downvote? I dont see anything wrong about this answer. I got no votes left for today, cant upvote it :)

Comment: Well that depends on the interpretation. I think the excercise is very unclear here. Look at Marks post: you could even interpret the "or exactly two b's" to mean "exactly two b's and any number of a's".

Comment: @Phild: The downvote was because I simply answered without an explanation at first ;)
Which is fair, with a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the first question is asking you to write a regular expression for the set of strings that do not match the provided regular expression.

For instance, suppose the question was asking for a regular expression for the set of strings *not* matched by `aa+` over {a}.  Well, here are a few strings that do match:

- 'aa'
- 'aaaa'
- 'aaaaa'

What are some strings that do not match?  Here are the only two:

- ''
- 'a'

A regex for the latter set is `a?`.

Regarding the second question, I would suggest drumming up some positive and negative test cases.  Run some strings like this through your regex and see what happens:

- 'a'  (should pass)
- 'aaa'  (should pass)
- 'bb'  (should pass)
- ''  (should fail)
- 'aa'  (should fail)
- 'aba'  (should fail)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(a+b)*a(a+b)*` just means: there **has** to be an `a` inside the string. The only strings that cant be generated by this expression are those: `b*`

Comment: Just see that we have different meanings of the `+` sign here: my prof always used it as an `or` operator, while in most real implementations it is used as the 'one or more' operator, and the `|` sign means `or`.

Answer (score 0):

This expression means that RE must contain Atleast 1 'A' in the expression.

this expression doest not accept

'b'
'b'*
or 
Empty set